# How to return a Method C#

Tags: c#, operators

I need to return a method in an operator function.

```
        public int Add()
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public static int operator +()
        {
            return Add;
        }
```

I will need to do this for a multiply, subtract and divide operator/function too.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you need to return the result of a method call?  Or return a method delegate?

Comment: I need to return the return value of Add()

Comment: You can take a look at the answers below and see which meets your needs, there was confusion as to the intention, but a few return the results of `Add()` *assuming* the operator+ is adding together two instances of the class.

Comment: you Overloaded the + operator for the 'class'.So where as normally 1+1 is 2 for your class 1+1 is 1

Comment: Stop down-voting! This is a legitimate programming question that belongs on StackOverflow, no matter how absurd the actual intention is. Some of the *best* questions refer to obscure or weird things in the language.

Comment: I'm not sure you're using your terms correctly: the return value of `Add` will always be `1`.  The `Add` Method is also returnable (as in your case), but it's going to return a `Func` object that you can later call using either the `()` operator, or the `Invoke` Method.

Comment: @MaxWillmo: Returning *the return value of Add()* is in no way the same as *returning the Add method itself*. But you need to understand that operators need operands, too...

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: I don't think the OP should actually be doing anything strange here - he's just misunderstood or miscommunicated what he *is* meant to be doing, I suspect.

Comment: It looks do me like he wants the `+` operator to use the `Add` function (almost as if an operator itself is an expression that evaluates to a function, then the operands become arguments). Almost like a compile-time (or perhaps runtime) substitution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't declare parameterless operators. You *can* declare an operator to return an appropriate delegate - e.g. `Func<int>` - but it would be a pretty odd thing to do, IMO.

If you can tell us more about what you're trying to achieve, we can probably help you to work out a cleaner design.

Here's a pretty strange example overloading the unary + operator:

```
using System;

class Weird
{
    private readonly int amount;

    public Weird(int amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    private int Add(int original)
    {
        return original + amount;
    }

    // Very strange. Please don't do this.
    public static Func<int, int> operator +(Weird weird)
    {
        return weird.Add;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Weird weird = new Weird(2);
        Func<int, int> func = +weird;
        Console.WriteLine(func(3));
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you're just trying to implement a `Rational` type, you're more likely to want:

```
public struct Rational
{
    // Other members

    public Rational Add(Rational other)
    {
        ...
    }

    public static Rational operator +(Rational left, Rational right)
    {
        return left.Add(right);
    }
}
```

Comment: my eyes... the goggles do nothing... ;0)

Comment: "Implement methods add, sub, multiply, divide as well as the operators" These are for a rational numbers project.

Comment: @MaxWillmo: That's not really enough context... why would the operators need to return methods? They will be given operands, so you should return the result of applying the operator to the operands...

Answer (score 9):

This is what you SEEM to be trying to do, but your example makes it difficult to tell.  So, from your comments in other answers it looks like you want to add, subtract, multiply, divide Rational numbers, which means the result should be a Rational as well (not an int).

Thus, you could define each of your methods, then implement operators to call those.  The operators are always static, thus you'd need to check for `null` and handle as appropriate (in this case, I'll just throw `ArgumentNullException`):

```
public class Rational
{
    public Rational Add(Rational other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");

        return // <-- return actual addition result here
    }

    public static Rational operator +(Rational left, Rational right)
    {
        if (left == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("left");

        return left.Add(right);
    }

    public Rational Subtract(Rational other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");

        return  // <-- return actual subtraction result here
    }

    public static Rational operator -(Rational left, Rational right)
    {
        if (left == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("left");

        return left.Subtract(right);
    }

    public Rational Multiply(Rational other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");

        return // <-- return actual multiplication result here
    }

    public static Rational operator *(Rational left, Rational right)
    {
        if (left == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("left");

        return left.Multiply(right);
    }

    public Rational Divide(Rational other)
    {
        if (other == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("other");

        return  // <-- return actual division result here
    }

    public static Rational operator /(Rational left, Rational right)
    {
        if (left == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("left");

        return left.Divide(right);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple. Just call the Add method:

```
return Add();
```

Comment: Typo, that doesn't do it either.

Comment: He need to execute the + operator on the derived object. As the Add function overloads the original operator result will always be 1.

Answer (score 0):

[C Sharp - Lesson 18: Overloading Operators](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson18.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can overload the + operator for int's! You would have to create your own wrapper class or struct instead:

```
public struct MyInt
{
    private int _value;

    public MyInt(int value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    public static MyInt operator +(MyInt a, MyInt b)
    {
        return new MyInt(a._value + b._value);
    }

    public static implicit operator MyInt(int intValue)
    {
        return new MyInt(intValue);
    }

    public static explicit operator int(MyInt x)
    {
        return x.Value;
    }
}
```

Then you are free to do with '+' what ever you want to do with it.

The implicit operator automatically converts int's to MyInt. So you could assign like this: `MyInt x = 7;`

The explicit operator converts MyInt's to int's like: `int i = (int)x;` where x is a MyInt.

Comment: You can also overload the ++ operator: 
`public static MyInt operator ++(MyInt a)
{
 return new MyInt(a._value + 1);
}`